# Cleaning text: For loop is way faster than the map function. Why is that?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, data-cleaning, text-classification

When I search the internet, everyone seems to agree on the fact that map is usually 'better' than a for loop.
In all text-cleaning examples I have seen, in books as well as on the internet, everyone seems to write their text-cleaning actions using the map function.

But how come my loop is way faster than the map?

```
import textacy.preprocessing as tprep

df1 = df
df2 = df

def normalize(text):
    text = tprep.normalize.hyphenated_words(text)
    text = tprep.normalize.quotation_marks(text)
    text = tprep.normalize.unicode(text)
    text = tprep.remove.accents(text)
    text = tprep.replace.urls(text)
    text = tprep.replace.emails(text)
    text = tprep.replace.phone_numbers(text)
    return text

%%time
for value in df1['text']:
    df1['text'] = df1['text'].map(normalize)
```

*CPU times: user 41.9 s, sys: 226 ms, total: 42.1 s
Wall time: 42.5 s*

```
%%time
for i, row in df2.iterrows():
    content = row['text']
    result = normalize(content) 
    df2.loc[i,['text']] = result
```

*CPU times: user 607 ms, sys: 3.9 ms, total: 611 ms
Wall time: 613 ms*

I tried it out with other functions that I wrote as well. They are all faster using a for loop. The outcome is the same, tough. What am I missing here?

Comment: *"everyone seems to agree on the fact that map is usually 'better' than a for loop"* - Citation needed.

Comment: Did you run these in the same interpreter session?  Note that when you do `df1 = df; df2 = df`, `df1` and `df2` are both referencing the *same* dataframe.  It's certainly possible that the `df2` loop is faster because it didn't have any work left to do.  Try changing those two lines to use `df.copy()` and see if you get the same results.

Comment: I think `apply` is better suited for transformations rather than `map`.

Answer (score 1):

```
for value in df1['text']:
    df1['text'] = df1['text'].map(normalize)
```

You perform the whole column processing `len(df1)` times here. Shouldn't you just do it once?